# Specifying a space in the sonar.ProjectName option

Tags: python, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I have built a rule in my setup.py file that allows my to call sonar scanner from within eclipse. To do this I have had to make use of sonar-scanners command line arguments. I run into a problem however when specifying project names with spaces in. As I'm running on a windows PC my command line look like ths

```
 ['cmd', '/c', u'sonar-scanner -Dsonar.projectKey=TL:python -Dsonar.projectName=Trade Loader -Dsonar.projectVersion=1.4 -Dsonar.sources=tradeloader -Dsonar.host.url=http://tsw:9000']
```

This gives the error:

```
ERROR: Unrecognized option: Loader
```

i.e. it doesn't like the space

I tried to surround the name with quotes:

```
['cmd', '/c', u"sonar-scanner -Dsonar.projectKey=TL:python -Dsonar.projectName='Trade Loader' -Dsonar.projectVersion=1.4 -Dsonar.sources=tradeloader -Dsonar.host.url=http://tsw:9000"]
```

but that also fails in the same way:

```
ERROR: Unrecognized option: Loader'
```

Does anyone know how I can specify a project name with spaces on the command line?

**Edit:**

So, my problem came from specifying the entire command as a single string. To get this to work you need to make each argument a separate string.

e.g.:

```
['cmd', '/c', 'sonar-scanner', '-Dsonar.projectKey=TL:python', '-Dsonar.projectName=Trade Loader', u'-Dsonar.projectVersion=1.4', '-Dsonar.sources=tradeloader', '-Dsonar.host.url=http://tsw:9000']
```

Answer (score 2):

In the root of your project create a file named `sonar-project.properties` and set your key/value property pairs there, one per line.

Comment: I presume you are saying that I cannot set a project name with spaces on the command line?

Comment: i highly recommend the usage of sonar-project.properties files - in my opinion you gain a lot out of it -> you can put that file into your Versioning System, and it changes with your code. So when you need it for jenkins builds, or in other environments, you do not need to configure them there, you just start the scanner. Everything is there!